# How to solve heap buffer overflow

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

I am having hard time solving problem with my program. It seems to be running as it should. But when I compile it with adress sanitizer I get heap buffer overflow. The function gets a 2d array containg a word to look for - replace [a][0] and a word next to it, which will be later used to replace it.

```
const char * findInArray(const char * (*replace)[2], char * start) // function goes through a array 'start' and searches if the word is also in 'replace'
{
  
  char * copy = (char *) malloc (strlen(start)+1); // I made a copy of a field, so I do not modify the one I passed to function
  char * total = (char *) malloc (strlen(start)+2); // Here I will add words from copy one by one

  memmove(copy,start,strlen(start)+1); // I fill the copy array

  char * tokens = strtok (copy," "); // I split copy array 
  while (tokens != NULL)
  {
  printf("%lu ",strlen(total));
  memmove(total+strlen(total)+1,tokens,strlen(tokens)); // I add words to a new array                                                                    one by one
  memmove (total + strlen(total)," ",1); // at the end of each word I add space
  for (int i = 0 ; replace[i][0] != NULL; i++) // I search if word is in array or not, if yes I return its adress
    {const char *ptr = strstr(total,replace[i][0]); 
    if (ptr != NULL) // If there is match - I return pointer to a word that will be replaced
      {
        free (total);
        return replace[i][0];
      }
    }
    //printf("%s\n",tokens);
    tokens = strtok(NULL, " ");
  }
  free (total);
  return NULL;
  
}
```

The problem if I understand it correctly is that I read values to total array, when It already has been allocated - which does not make a lot of sense to me.
Here is the error message:

```
==58229==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x000104d00bbb at pc 0x000102c7468c bp 0x00016d562b20 sp 0x00016d5622d8
READ of size 44 at 0x000104d00bbb thread T0
    #0 0x102c74688 in wrap_strlen+0x164 (libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib:arm64e+0x14688)
    #1 0x10289e4dc in findInArray test 4.c:39 // the line of moving memory to total
    #2 0x10289ee14 in newSpeak test 4.c:129
    #3 0x10289f880 in main test 4.c:186
    #4 0x1b4df7e4c  (<unknown module>)

0x000104d00bbb is located 0 bytes to the right of 43-byte region [0x000104d00b90,0x000104d00bbb)
allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x102c9eca8 in wrap_malloc+0x94 (libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib:arm64e+0x3eca8)
    #1 0x10289e480 in findInArray test 4.c:31 // the line of allocating total array
    #2 0x10289ee14 in newSpeak test 4.c:129
    #3 0x10289f880 in main test 4.c:186
    #4 0x1b4df7e4c  (<unknown module>)
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: `malloc (strlen(start)+2);` only allows room to concatenate a string of length `1` and there is no `realloc`.

Comment: It is already the size, what it will be eventually. I allocate it size of the array i pass to function and in the end the array will be max same size as inputed. I just cut it to pieces and then put them back together.

Comment: You're calling strlen(total) while total has been malloced, but not filled with any data.

Comment: After the `malloc` call for `total`, add `*total = 0;` to ensure the `strlen` on it works correctly.

Comment: Tried adding *total = 0, but unfortunatelly it didnt solve my problem. As for calling strlen(total) I believe it returns 0, which is what I want, in the first appending. But thanks for response either way.

Comment: Got to be honest, I'm struggling to understand what this code is meant to do. 'replace' seems to have many layers of indirection. You have a memory leak for the 'copy' array too.

Comment: I tried to clarify it a bit more.

Comment: As @EricPostpischil said, if you gave a minimal, reproducible example, we could compile it and maybe debug it. As it is, you might want to step through it in a debugger and see where it goes wrong. Some info on using a debugger with the address sanitiser is [here](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerAndDebugger). If I was coding this, I'd make a function that checks if a single word is in the input, then call it in a loop. Might make things slightly simpler.